# Type in text field - guess location

Tags: google-maps

I need the user to be able to type in a text field an address and for Google to autocomplete this with the location that the user is typing, also I need to know the geolocation for this.

Am I right in thinking that I'll need to use Google's "Places autocomplete" or is there a different lib I may have missed?

Answer (score 1):

I've acomplished this by using the Google's Autocomplete. Here you have example on AngularJS:

```
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
      } else {
        updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
      }
    });
  }

  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    scope.location = place.formatted_address;

  });

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
```